# UITextField's hidden property not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, click, uitextfield, hidden

In my app for iPhone/iPad (in Objective-C), there are some `UITextFields` which I am adding progrmatically and these further added to array.

I want to set the `hidden` property on some button click (where I found the particular `UITextField` by traversing the array).

When I set the `textfilled.hidden = true` (at button click event), then it is not hidden instead in disabled mode and if I again set `textfilled.hidden = false`, then it enables.

I have tried changing other properties like text, background color etc. at the same level all works fine except the hidden property.

Note: If it set `textfilled.hidden = true` after adding the text field (with the same object of `UITextField`) then it hides perfectly.

UPDATE: I have used the following code:

```
UITextField *textField=[[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, 60, 20)] autorelease];
    textField.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];    
    textField.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(handleEnterPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
    [capturedImage addSubview:textField];
    [noteTextArray addObject:textField];
```

In this I am creating a UITextField and adding it to array(noteTextArray) and the calling the .hidden property here:

```
-(void)handleEnterPressed:(UITextField *)textField 
{
for(UITextField *noteText in noteTextArray)
{
    if(noteText.tag==textField.tag)
    {
        noteText.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
        noteText.text=@"Hi";
        noteText.hidden=true;
    }
}
}
```

But it is not hiding the text field.

Please let me know if somebody has any idea or solution.

UPDATE 1:  Image has been taken by capturing the screenshot of current view of WebView

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webview.frame.size,NO,0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    [webview.layer renderInContext: context];
    capturedImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And the image further added to uiscrollviewer:

```
 scrollViewer.delegate=self;    
        scrollViewer.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        capturedImage.contentMode= UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        scrollViewer.userInteractionEnabled=true;
        scrollViewer.contentMode= UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        scrollViewer.scrollEnabled=YES;
        [scrollViewer setBouncesZoom:YES];
        scrollViewer.clipsToBounds= YES;
        scrollViewer.contentSize = capturedImage.image.size;
        scrollViewer.minimumZoomScale=0.1;
        scrollViewer.maximumZoomScale=5.0;
        scrollViewer.zoomScale=0.5;
        if(capturedImage.superview != scrollViewer)
        {
            [scrollViewer addSubview:capturedImage];
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Aadhira for making me correct !. Do you know the answer to the question? If Yes. please post the answer.

Comment: are you setting textfilled.hidden = true/false...... you should use textfilled.hidden = YES/NO instead.

Comment: @Ravin I have set both the ways but it didn't work at all:(

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you have written In NOTE.

Comment: @RachitTaneja, I have added the code I use in my app in the update area of my original post.

Comment: @MandeepKaur I have checked Your code by making a sample app.It is working fine in my case.You have to debug you code and print the description and tag of both the testField: noteText and textField.
May you will get some success.

Comment: I have debug my code and all works fine. If I hide the textfield at creation time then it hides, but in the event it just do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property cannot set as active and deactivate so This will be better approach if u set the property according to the situation like on button 1 pressed

```
textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

and on button pressed

```
textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
```

update:

```
   field.selected = TRUE;

    if([field isHidden])
{
    [field setHidden:FALSE];
}
else  
{
    [field setHidden:TRUE];
}
```

Update 2:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 20, 150, 20)];
    [self.view addSubview:field];
    field.placeholder = @"placeholder";
    field.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    field.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}

-(IBAction) btnPressed:(id)sender
{

    field.selected = TRUE;

        if([field isHidden])
    {
        [field setHidden:FALSE];
    }
    else  
    {
        [field setHidden:TRUE];
    }


}
```

update 3: please download the [sample](http://www.4shared.com/folder/1yiiHrbw/_online.html) code  (testTextField)

Comment: Hi @Kulss thanks for the reply, but I am not asking to how to set the textAlignment, I am asking how to show/hide it. As textfilled.hidden is not working as it should work.

Comment: check my above updated code this will definitely help u.. i have test this

Comment: did u connect textfield to the iboutlet. if u get any error print this error.

Comment: i am adding it progrmatically, so i can't connect it to the iboutlet. But i have tried changing the backgroundcolor and text in the handleEnterPressed event and all works fine.

Comment: check update2 , this worked well in my end ,i don't understand what error u get. share ur error message so that i can find the error

Comment: it still does not work..........I am not getting any error, it just  disabled when i set hidden=true(means i can't perform any action on that)

Comment: even when i sets the hidden=true, then the background color remains there but the text disappears.........is that can help you to help me!

Comment: can you please upload the sample code anywhere else as i don't have the premium account and can't have at this time :)

Comment: i have checked in my app that i am adding the textfield to the uiimageview(capturedImage) but i add it to the self.view instead of capturedImage then it works fine. Bit at this point my prblem is that if i don't add it to capturedImage the it will not be paaned along with the image(as per the functionality)

Comment: @mandeep ,thanks ..i thought even , after a long effort this will not make sense for u.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alpha property.

To hide:

```
textfield.alpha = 0;
```

To show again:

```
textfield.alpha = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code in my project, its working perfect. on very start it was not working because i didn't allocated noteTextArray.

so debug and check whether on UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit control moves to Method "handleEnterPressed", that's it. If it is in handleEnterPressed and noteTextArray is not empty then will work fine, there is nothing wrong with hidden property. I already told you problem is somewhere else.

so check whether noteTextArray is empty or not

Comment: I have checked all the inputs and all are having their respective values and events are working fine. But the problem remains same.  If I hidethe textfield at creation time then it hides, but in the event it just do not work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for tag checking - you have all the information in sender.
You might want to change your delegate method like this:

```
-(void)handleEnterPressed:(id)sender
{
  NSLog (@"delegate called fot textfield with tag %d",(UITextField *)sender.tag);

  (UITextField *)sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
  (UITextField *)sender.text=@"Hi";
  (UITextField *)sender.hidden=YES;
}
```

And check in console if your delegate method is called at all.

Comment: I have already tried this and does not work......it just hides my text and disable all the operations but the background color is still there:(

Comment: this is strange. Try [(UITextField *)sender setHidden: YES]; instead

Comment: Basically the code is write. i have checked in my app that i am adding the textfield to the uiimageview(capturedImage) but i add it to the self.view instead of capturedImage then it works fine. Bit at this point my prblem is that if i don't add it to capturedImage the it will not be panned along with the image(as per the functionality)

Comment: Understood. Try amending the question with the code that generates capturedImage. The problem must be there somewhere.

Comment: I have added the image capturing code in UPDATE 1 section of the original message.